# I have a proof that " For every set $S, ∅⊈S$" BUT I cannot find anything wrong.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

My proof is:
Let $S$ be a set, to show that $∅⊈S$, we must show that $∃x(x∈∅\implies x∉S)$ is true. Because $x∈∅$ is false, the conditional statement $x∈∅\implies x∉S$ is always true. Therefore, $∃x(x∈∅\implies x∉S)$ is true. This completes the proof.

I cannot find anything wrong.

Comment: This doesn't show that $\emptyset \notin S$.

Comment: "to show that $∅∉S$, we must show that $∃x(x∈∅\implies x∉S)$ is true": no, what you must show is $\forall x(x=∅\implies x∉S)$ (but you won't be able to show it because it is false for many $S$'s).

Comment: If you change the $\exists$ to $\forall$ you are showing that $\emptyset$ is disjoint from every set, which is true.

Comment: $\{\{\}\}~~~~~$

Comment: You misunderstood the interplay of negation and $\to$: $\subseteq$ is defined as $\forall x (x \in \emptyset \to x \in S)$. Thus, its negation $\nsubseteq$ will be $\lnot \forall x (x \in \emptyset \to x \in S)$ that is $\exists x (x \in \emptyset \land x \notin S)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Then how do you prove that ∃x(x∈∅∧x∉S) is false?

Comment: Because $x \in \emptyset$ is always false. The *emptyset* is .... empty, that means exactly: $\forall x \lnot (x \in \emptyset)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is very simple. It is **not** true that

> To show $\varnothing\not\subseteq S$ we must show that $\exists x(x\in\varnothing\implies x\notin S)$.

This is false. You have messed up the negation of "is a subset of".

Recall that $A\subseteq B$ is shorthand for
$$\forall x (x\in A\implies x\in B).$$
That means that $A\not\subseteq B$ is shorthand for:
\begin{align*}
\neg\left(\forall x(x\in A\implies x\in B)\right) &\iff \exists x\left(\neg\bigl( x\in A\implies x \in B\bigr)\right)\\
&\iff \exists x\bigl( (x\in A)\wedge \neg(x\in B)\bigr)\\
&\iff \exists x\bigl( (x\in A)\wedge (x\notin B)\bigr).
\end{align*}
This because the negation of $P\to Q$ is $P\wedge(\neg Q)$.

So what you actually *should* have is:

> To show $\varnothing\not\subseteq S$, we must show that $\exists x\bigl((x\in\varnothing)\wedge (x\notin S)\bigr)$.

Now note that $(x\in\varnothing)\wedge (x\notin S)$ is always **false**, since $x\in \varnothing$ is always false.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of subset, for any two sets $A,B$, we have $A \subseteq B$ if and only if

$$\forall x[x \in A \to x \in B]$$

Thus, we show $A \nsubseteq B$ by taking the negation of said formula

$
\begin{array}{11}
\neg \forall x[x \in A \to x \in B] & \\
\exists x \neg [x \in A \to x \in B] & \text{Negation Rules for Quantifiers} \\
\exists x \neg [\neg (x \in A) \vee x \in B] & \text{Implication Rule}\\
\exists x [\neg\neg (x \in A) \wedge \neg (x \in B)] & \text{DeMorgan's Law}\\
\exists x [x \in A \wedge \neg (x \in B)] & \text{Double Negation Elimination}\\
\exists x [x \in A \wedge x \notin B] & \text{Definition of $\notin$}\\
\end{array}
$

Thus, in order to show $\emptyset \nsubseteq S$ for every set $S$, you must prove

$$ \exists x [x \in \emptyset \wedge x \notin S] $$

for some arbitrary $S$. Of course, the first conjunct $x \in \emptyset$ is always false, so the formula is always false.